# PySpark 2.4.5: IllegalArgumentException when using PandasUDF

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying Pandas UDF and facing the IllegalArgumentException. I also tried replicating examples from PySpark Documentation [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=arrow#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) to check but still getting the error.

Following is the environment configuration

- python3.7
- Installed PySpark==2.4.5 using pip
- Installed PyArrow==0.16.0 using pip

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf('int', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)  
def min_udf(v):
    return v.min()

sorted(gdf.agg(min_udf(df.age)).collect())
```

Output

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-94a0a39bfe30> in <module>
----> 1 sorted(gdf.agg(min_udf(sample_data.sqft)).collect())

~/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    532         """
    533         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 534             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    535         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    536 

~/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o665.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 232, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessage(MessageSerializer.java:543)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNext(MessageChannelReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:132)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessage(MessageSerializer.java:543)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNext(MessageChannelReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:132)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by incompatibility between Spark and Arrow libraries. In general each Spark release supports only a narrow range of Arrow versions (within minor release). Additionally there are some format incompatibilities between Arrow versions.

You can check [the official documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/docs/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.md) for details

> Compatibility Setting for PyArrow >= 0.15.0 and Spark 2.3.x, 2.4.x
>
> Since Arrow 0.15.0, a change in the binary IPC format requires an environment variable to be compatible with previous versions of Arrow <= 0.14.1. This is only necessary to do for PySpark users with versions 2.3.x and 2.4.x that have manually upgraded PyArrow to 0.15.0. The following can be added to conf/spark-env.sh to use the legacy Arrow IPC format:
>
> ```
> ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1
> ```
>
> This will instruct PyArrow >= 0.15.0 to use the legacy IPC format with the older Arrow Java that is in Spark 2.3.x and 2.4.x. Not setting this environment variable will lead to a similar error as described in SPARK-29367 when running pandas_udfs or toPandas() with Arrow enabled. More information about the Arrow IPC change can be read on the Arrow 0.15.0 release blog.

In practice I'd recommend using exactly the same Arrow version as used for build:

- [0.8.0 for 2.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75cc3b2da9ee0b51ecf0f13169f2b634e36a60c4/pom.xml#L192)
- [0.10 for 2.4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1c65b1dae02029c5ad03061f1bab9bff4d22e70f/pom.xml#L193)
- [0.15.1 for 3.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/be5dfcd2f2e42976db65cf2306371f0e7a74d4cc/pom.xml#L201)

etc.